# Java: How to add a new line of String to the existing text file?

Tags: java

I'm what I am trying to do is saving all the scores of a game, but it seems like it's just overwriting the first line and not adding them to the next line. I need your help! Thank you in advance!

```
System.out.print("Enter Your Name: ");
    String name = inputName.nextLine();

    try {
        File highscore = new File("highscore.txt");

        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(highscore);
        if (highscore.exists()) {
            System.out.println("Score has been saved!");
        }           
        output.println(name + " - " + score);
        output.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to ask. Could you give a sample input and expected output as well?

Comment: Duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625234/how-to-append-text-to-an-existing-file-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(highscore, true));` instead of `PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(highscore);`

> As the second argument in the constructor tells the FileWriter to
>   append the input to the file rather than overwriting it.

```
 public class StreamFilter {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.out.print("Enter Your Name: ");
         Scanner inputName = new Scanner(System.in);
         String score="hui";
         String name = inputName.nextLine();

            try {
                File highscore = new File("highscore.txt");

                PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(highscore);//remove this
PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(highscore, true));//usethis,
                if (highscore.exists()) {
                    System.out.println("Score has been saved!");
                }           
                output.println(name + " - " + score);
                output.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to open the file in append mode, you have to use `FileWriter(String fileName, boolean appender)` constructor.

```
output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file_name, true));
```

Add the above line and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
output.println()
```

use

```
output.append()
```

that should work...